# How do you inject a factory function with Aurelia's DI container?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I'd like to make a third-party object on the `window` injectable so that I can test functionality independent of the third-party service. The component I'm trying to build is a simple wrapper around Disqus embedded comments. The factory I would like to use is as simple as

```
() => window.DISQUS
```

Has anyone been able to do this or know if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`registerInstance`](https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/blob/master/src/container.js#L61) with a string key like this:

```
container.registerInstance('disqus', window.DISQUS);
```

Then you can inject the disqus instance into your view models like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject('disqus')
export class Foo {
  constructor(disqus) {
    this.disqus = disqus;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you put that `container.registerInstance` code?

Comment: @Dustin take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35141543/725866) and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/73)