# How do you substitute HttpClient in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, json, aurelia

I'm brand new to Aurelia.

How would you change the following code to provide a dummy HttpClient, e.g. a json reader instead that would provide just a static set of json data, negating the need for a server in development.

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Users {
  heading = 'Github Users';
  users = [];

  constructor(http) {
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl('https://api.github.com/');
    });

    this.http = http;
  }

  activate() {
    return this.http.fetch('users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => this.users = users);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a couple steps required to get the demo code in your original post to a state where we can substitute HttpClient implementations.

## Step 1

Remove the configuration code in the class's constructor...

These lines:

**users.js**

```js
...
http.configure(config => {
  config
    .useStandardConfiguration()
    .withBaseUrl('https://api.github.com/');
});
...
```

Should move to the `main.js` file:

**main.js**

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  configureContainer(aurelia.container);  // <--------

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}

function configureContainer(container) {
  let http = new HttpClient();
  http.configure(config => {
    config
      .useStandardConfiguration()
      .withBaseUrl('https://api.github.com/');
  });
  container.registerInstance(HttpClient, http); // <---- this line ensures everyone that `@inject`s a `HttpClient` instance will get the instance we configured above.
}
```

Now our users.js file should look like this:

**users.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Users {
  heading = 'Github Users';
  users = [];

  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  activate() {
    return this.http.fetch('users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => this.users = users);
  }
}
```

## Step 2:

Mock the HttpClient.

The user.js module only uses the `fetch` method which returns a `Response` object that has a `json` method.  Here's a simple mock:

```js
let mockUsers = [...todo: create mock user data...];

let httpMock = {
  fetch: url => Promise.resolve({
    json: () => mockUsers
  })
};
```

## Step 3:

Reconfigure the container to use the http mock:

In step 1 we added a `configureContainer` function to the `main.js` module that registered a configured HttpClient instance in the container. If we wanted to use our mock version the `configureContainer` function would change to this:

**main.js**

```js
...

let mockUsers = [...todo: create mock user data...];

let httpMock = {
  fetch: url => Promise.resolve({
    json: () => mockUsers
  })
};

function configureContainer(container) {      
  container.registerInstance(HttpClient, httpMock);
}
```

More info on configuring the container here: https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/73

Comment: brilliant, @jdanyow :)

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility to provide static data for the application during development. Navigation Skeleton already comes with Gulp and BrowserSync, so we used those to fake API calls.

Let's say you load JSON data from `/api` virtual directory, so e.g.

```
GET /api/products
```

In this case your just need two things to fake it.

#### Put your mock data into files

Go to the root folder of your Aurelia app and create an `/api` folder.

Create a `/api/products` subfolder and put a new file called `GET.json`. This file should contain the JSON, e.g.

**GET.json**

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Keyboard", "price": "60$" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Mouse", "price": "20$" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Headphones", "price": "80$" }
]
```

#### Configure BrowserSync to mock your API calls

Navigate to `/build/tasks` folder and edit the `serve.js` file. Change the definition of serve task to the following code:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function(done) {
  browserSync({
    online: false,
    open: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.'],
      middleware: function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        // Mock API calls
        if (req.url.indexOf('/api/') > -1) {
          console.log('[serve] responding ' + req.method + ' ' + req.originalUrl);

          var jsonResponseUri = req._parsedUrl.pathname + '/' + req.method + '.json';

          // Require file for logging purpose, if not found require will 
          // throw an exception and middleware will cancel the retrieve action
          var jsonResponse = require('../..' + jsonResponseUri);

          // Replace the original call with retrieving json file as reply
          req.url = jsonResponseUri;
          req.method = 'GET';
        }

        next();
      }
    }
  }, done);
});
```

Now, when your run `gulp serve`, BrowserSync will be handling your API calls and serving them from the static files on disk.

You can see an example in my [github repo](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/mikhailio-samples/tree/master/aurelia-api-mocks) and more description in my [Mocking API calls in Aurelia](http://mikhail.io/2016/07/mocking-api-calls-in-aurelia/).

Comment: Will this approach work if your api calls are going to an external site ?