# How do I fake API responses for Aurelia?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have two scenarios

1. fake responses during testing
2. fake responses with the development servers (using webpack)

presuming that I'm injecting `HttpClient` from `aurelia-fetch-client` how can I fake the responses to this in these 2 scenario's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35141543/725866